# Unable to call curl in .hta using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, curl, vbscript, hta

For some reason I am not able to call curl.exe in .hta using JavaScript. Running the following (just an example) as .hta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            w=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
            w.run('"C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe" "https://www.google.com" -o t.txt')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

results in file not found error, though curl.exe definately exists in System32 directory. If I, however, call curl.exe located in different directory, that works fine, as well as just 'curl' if I add that directory to PATH. Also running e.g. notepad.exe or fc.exe in System32 directory works.

I tried also using VBScript to launch curl in .hta but that doesn't work either. If I however create .js with

```
w=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
w.run('"C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe" "https://www.google.com" -o t.txt')
```

or .vbs with

```
Set w = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
w.Run("""C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe"" ""https://www.google.com"" -o t.txt""")
```

both work well.

So what is the reason for curl not working when called in .hta? Is it blacklisted for some (security?) reasons, is there a bug somewhere, or am I just doing something wrong?

EDIT: Tried to call a .bat calling curl. Same story: if .bat calls C:\Windows\System32\curl it won't work, when called in .hta, but works when called by .js or .vbs. Calling SomeOtherDirectory\curl.exe works.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to type the write words to Google and [found what was wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/1359335/hta-cant-run-ie4uinit-exe). HTA files are run by 32 bit mshta.exe, which leads C:\Windows\System32 to redirect to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 where no curl.exe exists. Replacing System32 with Sysnative made .hta work.

```
w.run('"C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\curl.exe" "https://www.google.com" -o t.txt')
```